# Kentico - Multiple Choice Dual List Form Control

Tags: kentico

I found this [Multiple Choice Dual List (with Sort)](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/dual-list-multi-select-form-(with-sort)) form control and have a question about the sorting functionality. From the description, it looks like the sorting functionality only works if we have something like this  `CHARINDEX(','+CONVERT(varchar, ItemID)+',', ',1,3,2,5,4,')` in the `Order By` field. I tested with a couple of items and saw that if I hard-coded the `Order By` as instructed, it worked. Is there a way / something to put in the `Order By` so that it accepts the (new) order of the items in the second (red) box - without hard-coding? THANK YOU! [image]

My authors (the left box) are from a SQL query. 
The WHERE statement of my Repeater is like this, if it's of any help:
`'|' + '{%CurrentDocument.Authors#%}' + '|' LIKE '%|' + CONVERT(varchar, AuthorsID) + '|%'` Everything is working; I just need that sorting functionality to work dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easies way to achieve this would be implementation of some logic on the client with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

That would be my tool.  The example order by is meant to show kind of how it works, your order by would look like:

```
CHARINDEX(','+CONVERT(varchar,AuthorsID)+',', '{%CurrentDocument.Authors#%}')
```

Assuming that Authors is the field that has the multiselect with order form tool, and AuthorsID is the table's identity row.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the tool! I hope it'll work for me. I've tried something similar before your response and just tried it again now, but the new order doesn't work. Looks like `CurrentDocument.Authors` spits out list of authors in the same order as the one in the original list. Not sure if I missed anything.